# How do I get Central Time in my batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I have to basically use an if condition that is dependent on the current central time. How do I call the current CT ?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this batch script](http://adminspeak.wordpress.com/tag/batch-script-time-zone/) to audit / add / set time with different timezones on windows machines. For easier access, I am posting below the script:

```
@echo off
TITLE Check/Set Time Zone Configuration
COLOR 17

:OSCHK
FOR /F "tokens=4-5 delims=, " %%g IN ('wmic os get caption ^|find /I "Windows"') DO (IF /I "%%g"=="2003" (set OSVER=%%g) ELSE (IF /I "%%g"=="2008" (IF "%%g%%h"=="2008R2" (set OSVER=%%g%%h) ELSE set OSVER=%%g)))
FOR /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%g IN ('wmic os get caption ^|find /I "Windows"') DO (IF /I "%%g"=="7" set OSVER=%%g)

IF /I "%OSVER%"=="" (goto OSWARN) ELSE (goto TZRVW)

:OSWARN
echo.
echo.
echo *************************************
echo WARNING
echo *************************************
echo.
echo This script is designed to run on the following
echo Windows operating systems only:
echo Servers – 2003, 2008, 2008 R2
echo Clients – Windows 7
echo.
goto END

:TZRVW
cls
echo.
echo The time zone on this machine is:
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=*" %%g IN ('wmic timezone get description ^|find " "') Do (@echo %%g)
goto TZQRY

:TZQRY
echo.
SET TZQRY=
SET /P TZQRY=Do you need to change the Time Zone? (y/n/q to quit): %=%
echo.
IF /I "%TZQRY%"=="y" (goto TZSEL) ELSE (IF /I "%TZQRY%"=="n" (goto END) ELSE (IF /I "%TZQRY%"=="q" (goto END)))
IF /I NOT "%TZQRY%"=="y" (IF /I NOT "%TZQRY%"=="n" (IF /I NOT "%TZQRY%"=="q" goto TZQRY0))

:TZQRY0
echo.
echo You made an invalid entry – please try again.
echo.
pause
goto TZRVW

:TZSEL
cls
echo.
echo Which Time Zone should this machine have?
echo 1. Pacific Time
echo 2. Mountain Time
echo 3. Arizona
echo 4. Central Time
echo 5. Eastern Time
echo 6. Other

echo.
SET SYSTZ=
SET /P SYSTZ= %=%
IF /I "%SYSTZ%"=="1" (goto TZPAC) ELSE (IF /I "%SYSTZ%"=="2" (goto TZMTN) ELSE (IF /I "%SYSTZ%"=="3" (goto TZARZ) ELSE (IF /I "%SYSTZ%"=="4" (goto TZCEN) ELSE (IF /I "%SYSTZ%"=="5" (goto TZEAS) ELSE (IF /I "%SYSTZ%"=="6" (goto TZOTH))))))
IF /I NOT "%SYSTZ%"=="1" (IF /I NOT "%SYSTZ%"=="2" (IF /I NOT "%SYSTZ%"=="3" (IF /I NOT "%SYSTZ%"=="4" (IF /I NOT "%SYSTZ%"=="5" (IF /I NOT "%SYSTZ%"=="6" (goto TZSEL0))))))

:TZSEL0
echo.
echo You have made an invalid entry – please try again.
echo.
pause
goto TZSEL

:TZPAC
IF /I "%OSVER%"=="2003" (control timedate.cpl,,/Z Pacific Standard Time) ELSE (IF /I "%OSVER%"=="2008" (tzone -Zone Pacific Time) ELSE (IF /I "%OSVER%"=="2008R2" (tzutil /s "Pacific Standard Time") ELSE (IF /I "%OSVER%"=="7" (tzutil /s "Pacific Standard Time"))))
goto TZRVW

:TZMTN
IF /I "%OSVER%"=="2003" (control timedate.cpl,,/Z Mountain Standard Time) ELSE (IF /I "%OSVER%"=="2008" (tzone -Zone Mountain Time) ELSE (IF /I "%OSVER%"=="2008R2" (tzutil /s "Mountain Standard Time") ELSE (IF /I "%OSVER%"=="7" (tzutil /s "Mountain Standard Time"))))
goto TZRVW

:TZARZ
IF /I "%OSVER%"=="2003" (control timedate.cpl,,/Z US Mountain Standard Time) ELSE (IF /I "%OSVER%"=="2008" (tzone -Zone Arizona) ELSE (IF /I "%OSVER%"=="2008R2" (tzutil /s "US Mountain Standard Time") ELSE (IF /I "%OSVER%"=="7" (tzutil /s "US Mountain Standard Time"))))
goto TZRVW

:TZCEN
IF /I "%OSVER%"=="2003" (control timedate.cpl,,/Z Central Standard Time) ELSE (IF /I "%OSVER%"=="2008" (tzone -Zone "Central Time (US & Canada)") ELSE (IF /I "%OSVER%"=="2008R2" (tzutil /s "Central Standard Time") ELSE (IF /I "%OSVER%"=="7" (tzutil /s "Central Standard Time"))))
goto TZRVW

:TZEAS
IF /I "%OSVER%"=="2003" (control timedate.cpl,,/Z Eastern Standard Time) ELSE (IF /I "%OSVER%"=="2008" (tzone -Zone Eastern Time) ELSE (IF /I "%OSVER%"=="2008R2" (tzutil /s "Eastern Standard Time") ELSE (IF /I "%OSVER%"=="7" (tzutil /s "Eastern Standard Time"))))
goto TZRVW

:TZOTH
echo.
echo Control Panel will now open so you
echo can set the time zone manually.
start control timedate.cpl
echo.
pause
goto TZRVW

:END
echo Exiting script…
echo.
ping localhost -n 5 >NUL
EXIT
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thats a good link. But it is a link. You could have done that as a comment.

Comment: Dont you think that is a little too much for what the OP asked? #outOfContext ?

Comment: Thanks for the quick help guys! Will test it out.